# Combobox ElseIF statement

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on this for a while, I have a Userform with 3 comboboxes, each assigned to a list of values. I can currently only get the third combobox working "Storagebin", where once I select a value and press search, it fills in the remaining boxes.
I am looking for the code that, whatever combobox I put text in, returns the values. With the code provided nothing returns for "Oldmaterialnumber" and "Materialnumber"
Thank you!

```
Private Sub Search_Click()

If Len(Oldmaterialnumber.Text) <> 0 Then

row_number = row_number + 1
item_in_review = Sheets("Database").Range("B" & row_number)
If item_in_review = Oldmaterialnumber.Text Then
    Materialnumber.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("A" & row_number)
    Storagebin.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("C" & row_number)
    Olddescription.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("D" & row_number)
 End If


ElseIf Len(Materialnumber.Text) <> 0 Then

row_number = row_number + 1
item_in_review = Sheets("Database").Range("A" & row_number)
If item_in_review = Materialnumber.Text Then
    Oldmaterialnumber.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("B" & row_number)
    Storagebin.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("C" & row_number)
    Olddescription.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("D" & row_number)
End If



ElseIf Len(Storagebin.Text) <> 0 Then

row_number = 0
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
item_in_review = Sheets("Database").Range("C" & row_number)
If item_in_review = Storagebin.Text Then
    Materialnumber.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("A" & row_number)
    Oldmaterialnumber.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("B" & row_number)
    Olddescription.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("D" & row_number)
End If

Loop Until item_in_review = ""

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get each combo box to have the same selection?  E.g. If you select the first item in the first combo box then the other two will also show the first item?

Comment: Hi @DarrenBartrup-Cook. No, I have 4 columns with data on a seperate sheet. At the moment I can only chose a value in the "Storagebin" combobox, and once I press search it finds the other values in the colmuns related to that value. I.e I chose JVX-123 and it fills in the combobox for Materialnumber, Oldmaterialnumber and the destcription too. I want to be able to chose any value from any of the comboboxes and for it to update the other fields as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
If Len(Oldmaterialnumber.Text) <> 0 Then
    lastrow = Sheets("Database").Cells(Sheets("Database").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        item_in_review = Sheets("Database").Range("B" & i)
        If item_in_review = Oldmaterialnumber.Text Then
            Materialnumber.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("A" & i)
            Storagebin.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("C" & i)
            Olddescription.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("D" & i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End If

If Len(Materialnumber.Text) <> 0 Then
    lastrow = Sheets("Database").Cells(Sheets("Database").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        item_in_review = Sheets("Database").Range("A" & i)
        If item_in_review = Materialnumber.Text Then
            Oldmaterialnumber.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("B" & i)
            Storagebin.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("C" & i)
            Olddescription.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("D" & i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End If

If Len(Storagebin.Text) <> 0 Then
    lastrow = Sheets("Database").Cells(Sheets("Database").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        item_in_review = Sheets("Database").Range("C" & i)
        If item_in_review = Storagebin.Text Then
            Materialnumber.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("A" & i)
            Oldmaterialnumber.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("B" & i)
            Olddescription.Text = Sheets("Database").Range("D" & i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You absolutely nailed it. Thanks a million, spent ages on that!

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a different approach. It took a little longer but you may still like to take a look. The code below loads columns A:D from your "Database" worksheet into the 3 combo boxes on your form, including column D which goes into a hidden column in one of them (actually CbxBin). When you select one of the items in one of the combo boxes the others align automatically, referring to each other instead of the worksheet. There is no need for a search button (or a search, in fact). Updating occurs when a selection is made on the form. So, you select an item in a combo box and click elsewhere (anywhere) to update.

This may not be the best solution yet. I used the combo boxes' `Update` event so that you can type in your CBXs. If you intend to strictly only select from the drop-downs change the code to use the `Change` event which gives you an instant update without the need to click elsewhere.

To test this code, install the first part in a standard code module (your Module1, I presume), where it replaces your existing `Button1` procedure. Make sure that the Enum is at the top of the code sheet.

```
Option Explicit
    Enum Ndb                                        ' Database columns
        ' 22 Jan 2018
        NdbMatNum = 1                               ' 1 = column A
        NdbOldMatNum
        NdbBin
        NdbOldDesc
    End Enum

    Sub Button1()
        ' 22 Jan 2018

        Dim MyForm As SetCbxs

        Set MyForm = New SetCbxs
        MyForm.Show
        Unload MyForm
    End Sub
```

Rename the Userform as "SetCbxs" or change the above code to mention the name of your form. It is mentioned twice in the `Button1` proc, and that is all it takes.

Install the second part of the code in the code sheet of the user form. The form must have 3 combo boxes named "CbxMatNum", "CbxOldMatNum", and "CbxBin". It also need one text box named "TbxOldDesc" as well as access to your "DataBase" worksheet to read data from. The code also provides for a command button by the name of "CmdOK".

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' 22 Jan 2018

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim IsBin As Boolean
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' last row
    Dim C As Long                               ' column

    With Worksheets("Database")                 ' change as appropriate
        ' presume that all columns are of the same length
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, NdbMatNum).End(xlUp).Row
        For C = NdbMatNum To NdbBin             ' columns A:C
            IsBin = C = NdbBin                  ' include column D in CbxBin
            ' start in row 2, presuming that row 1 holds captions
            Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2, C), .Cells(Rl, C - CInt(IsBin)))
            Arr = Rng.Value
            With Me.Controls(CtlName(C))
                .List = Arr
                .ListIndex = 0
                .ColumnCount = 1 - CInt(IsBin)  ' 2 columns for CbxBin
                If IsBin Then
                    ' hide 2nd column in dropdown
                    .ColumnWidths = .Width - 8 & "pt, 0 pt"
                End If
            End With
        Next C
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CmdOK_Click()
    ' 22 Jan 2018
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CbxBin_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ' 22 Jan 2018
    UpdateForm NdbBin
End Sub

Private Sub CbxMatNum_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ' 22 Jan 2018
    UpdateForm NdbMatNum
End Sub

Private Sub CbxOldMatNum_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ' 22 Jan 2018
    UpdateForm NdbOldMatNum
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateForm(ByVal CbxId As Ndb)
    ' 22 Jan 2018

    Dim i As Ndb
    Dim R As Integer

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    R = Me.Controls(CtlName(CbxId)).ListIndex
    For i = NdbMatNum To NdbBin             ' each of the 3 Cbx's
        If i <> CbxId Then
            Me.Controls(CtlName(i)).ListIndex = R
        End If
        TbxOldDesc.Text = CbxBin.Column(1)  ' Column is zero-based
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Function CtlName(ByVal Id As Long) As String
    ' 22 Jan 2018
    ' better not to repeat the names everwhere in the code:
    ' first item's index = 0
    CtlName = Split("CbxMatNum CbxOldMatNum CbxBin")(Id - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @variatus Just wondering what I should rename for the CbxID, it's giving me a "user-defined type not found" for the code "Private Sub UpdateForm(ByVal CbxId As Ndb)" I tried renaming to Userform but that failed also.

Comment: VBA is complaining about the Enum `Ndb` claiming it to be missing. It should be at the top of the code sheet, before any procedures.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to VBA, just giving me a run time error 70 Sub Button1()

UserForm.Show


End Sub

As I have that macro set up to show me the Userform, I sorted the Ndb problem, thank you!

Comment: Just realised " Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()" is doing just that, which is probably causing the error.

Comment: I suspect the code can't gain access to your worksheet. It might be protected or in a different folder. Where was your original code? It seemed to access the worksheet all right.

Comment: Now run-time error 9: Subscript out of range! Is that to do with CbxBin being allocated 2 columns? The reason I dont include D is it is just a description, so I do not want the engineers to search by that!

Comment: On which line of code do you get the error? Is it the worksheet name? No, the second column is invisible. I used it to fill the text box for the old description. I thought that TBX is for information only. The user can see it but he can do nothing about it.

Comment: That is correct, the TBX is just for information only. I get the error on Sub Button1()

UserForm.Show

End Sub

in Module 1, it's just a button I assigned to open the userform!

Comment: Place the cursor in the Initialise procedure and press F5. See where it stops.

Comment: It stops with the error, I press debug and it goes into Module 1: Genereal and shows Sub Button1()

UserForm.Show

End Sub

Something is blocking the button, and in term the Userform wont open and run!

Comment: Let me get this straight: (1) The code is in the userform's code sheet. (2) You place the cursor in the `Initialize` procedure in the userform's code sheet. (3) You press F5. (4) An error No. 9 occurs. (5) When you press `Debug` the line `UserForm.Show` in `Module1.Button1` is highlighted. Please confirm.

Comment: Apologies.. There is a problem with the button that wasnt there before but the Initialize procedure problem occurs on line "Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, NdbMatNum).End(xlUp).Row" It comes up "constant expression required" and highlights "NdbMatNum" in blue and Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() in yellow

Comment: The particular error you encountered is usually caused by some syntax error unrelated to the indicated error. It just might be that the Enum doesn't feel happy in the class module. So I created a `Button1` proc for you and moved the Enum with it. I also remnoved the `Unload Me` command from the `CmdOK` proc. Best, please install the entire thing once again observing the added instructions above. If you still get an error after that, neutralise all your other code in the workbook (just rem it all out with apostrophes). This code is tested and works. It should work for you, too.

Comment: After a bit of confusion, it wasn't running as Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() needed to be re named as Private Sub SetCbxs_Initialize().  "  TbxOldDesc.Text = CbxBin.Column(1)  ' Column is zero-based" Is causing an error "Could not get the column property"

Comment: `Private Sub SetCbxs_Initialize()` doesn't work for me (Excel 2010). Try replacing line that errors out with 
`With CbxBin
            TbxOldDesc.Text = .Column(1, .ListIndex) ' Column is zero-based
        End With` (Totally 3 lines in place of one)

Comment: Place this line of code in the procedure `FormUpdating': `Debug.Print "Updating: " & Me.Controls(CtlName(CbxId)).Name"`.  In my version of Excel `FormUpdating` doesn't run during initialisation. If your version works differently you would see CbxMatNum calling `FormUpdating` before CbxBin has been loaded. If so, you might try turning off `Application.EnableEvents` while the initializing proc runs.